# Android LVL Library - Market Licensing

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I'm trying to use Google LVL Licensing library. I already downloaded the library from Android SDK Manager, but when I tried to import it to my project I get the error that it doesn't exist.

My import is the following:

```
import com.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
import com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;
```

I’d appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the library to your project classpath / Build path?

Comment: No I didn't but I can't find it anywhere in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#download-lvl). The part Setting Up the Licensing Verification Library:

> After downloading the LVL to your computer, you need to set it up in
>   your development environment, either as an Android library project or
>   by copying (or importing) the library sources directly into your
>   existing application package. In general, using the LVL as a library
>   project is recommended, since it lets you reuse your licensing code
>   across multiple applications and maintain it more easily over time.
>   Note that the LVL is not designed to be compiled separately and added
>   to an application as a static .jar file.